How to correctly open uproject without visual studio?
I have a c++ unreal project, everytime I launch IDE through Visual Studio, it works fine, but if I right click uproject file then cilck Open, IDE will open but pops many warnings and project is in a mess. I figure out that's because dlls in Binaries/Win64 is not loaded, I'm wondering how can I open uproject directly without Visual Studio?

I don't quite understand the meaning of the phrase "launch IDE through Visual Studio." Could you upload some images to provide more information, such as how you're operating, whether you created the Unreal project yourself or downloaded it, etc.? This way, I can better assist you. Generally speaking, a .uproject file can be opened using the Unreal Editor.

"launch IDE through Visual Studio" means open ue c++ sln project file in VS, then ctrl+f5 to launch UE. And I already know why it worked incorrect by right click a c++ uproject to open, because UE opens project with UnrealEditor.exe, the correct way to open a c++ uproject is open uproject with UnrealEditor-Win64-DebugGame.exe which lays in EngineDir\Binaries\Win64\
